# How to generate a specific number of random binaries with probablities proportional to given values?

Tags: probability, simulation, excel, weighted-sampling

I have such a matrix in an excel sheet. It has 140 cells. I want to generate 20 binaries randomly.  However, the probability of generating "1" in each cell is proportional to cell's value. Namely, most of the 1's should be generated in the top rows, since each cell's values are larger at tops.

[image]

For example one possible generated sample can be:

[image]

How can I do that in an excel spreadsheet? I will be very glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This questions is probably off topic since it is about Excel and not statistics.

Comment: Still it is easy to come up with a formula that make sures P(X=1) reduces as we go down... for example: ROUND(RAND()-0.4*$A1/20,0) where you have added the number of the row to the A column.

Comment: Thanks @snoram. That is close to what I want, but not exact. That formula will generate not exact 20 binaries, It will produce around 20 binaries.